# Populate Content and Featured Image in Wordpress Post edit screen from ajax response

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am stuck again. I am working on Wordpress Post edit screen in which i need to populate post content and post Featured image from an Ajax Response.
I tried a lot myself but it didn't work for Content Editor because Wordpress use tinymce editor as WYSIWYG editor. Any idea how to do this?
I also need to populate image for which I am receiving image url from the AJAX response and I need to set this images as featured image in Wordpress Post edit screen.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i found a way to set content in WP Content Editor using the ajax response.
Below is the code.

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(response.DESCRIPTION);
```

Using this you can set content in the Content Editor of Post Edit screen.
Wordpress uses TinyMCE WYSIWYG Editor for it Content Editor. :D

But i still need to search how to set featured_image using ajax response. This is the second thing left in question